# How do I set CommandParameter in XAML?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I have the following XAML:

```
   <dxg:GridControl Name="theGrid" DataSource="{Binding Path=Groupings}">
       <dxg:GridControl.ContextMenu>
           <ContextMenu>
               <MenuItem x:Name="gridprint" Command="{Binding Path=GridPrintCommand}"/>
           </ContextMenu>
       </dxg:GridControl.ContextMenu>
   </dxg:GridControl>
```

When GridPrintCommand executes, its parameter to the GridPrintCommand.Execute(param) method is null.  I want to set the parameter to the grid control.  I can do that in the code-behind like this:

```
gridprint.CommandParameter = theGrid;
```

This works fine.  But I'm trying to set the same thing (CommandParameter) in the XAML, and I just can't get it right!  Everything I put results in a BindingExpressionError or a null parameter.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="gridprint"
    CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource=
         {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
```

ContextMenus are not part of the WPF's normal VisualTree, so you have to bind using the PlacementTarget to get the object the ContextMenu is attached to

Comment: Thanks, after three days searching I find that **ContextMenus are not part of the WPF's normal VisualTree, so you have to bind using the PlacementTarget to get the object the ContextMenu is attached to**

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be this

```
<dxg:GridControl Name="theGrid" DataSource="{Binding Path=Groupings}">
  <dxg:GridControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem x:Name="gridprint"
        Command="{Binding Path=GridPrintCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=theGrid}"
      />
    </ContextMenu>
  </dxg:GridControl.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: If I try that, I get this error message: `System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=theGrid'. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name='gridprint'); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')`

Comment: if not mistaken, is something related to the namespaces between the ContextMeny and the GridControl.