# Is there a way to determine where a WPF Binding is declared/created?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a project which is throwing some data binding errors. One example is:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')`

My question is whether there is a way to determine where this binding is actually declared (either it is declared in XAML or in code).

What I've tried so far:

- added a debug trace for the System.Windows.Data namespace with level set o All; this did not produce any more useful information
- tried doing a text-search in the project for the word **Binding** in hopes of locating all binding expressions that have the Path set to `HorizontalContentAlignment`; I found only one and removed it but I'm still getting the message which seems to indicate that that was not the faulty one..

Do you know of any other tricks to make WPF spit out some more useful information about where exactly is this binding declared?

*UPDATE*

After a little bit more searching I'm pretty sure this is somehow caused by a style being applied to a `MenuItem`. However, I'm still not able to pin-point the location where the faulty binding is being declared..

**UPDATE 2**

I found the problem. However the question still remains since finding the issue was mostly a matter of searching in the dark based on the limited info in the error message.

As it turns out, the binding is declared in a style. And the style is not in my application. It's probably the default style for `MenuItem`. So to fix the issue for now I've just manually set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` on all `MenuItems`. The reason for the error is somehow related to order of operations as this `MenuItem` is generated in code. I'll post a new question on that separately.

So, for now, the moral of the story is that I feel that there needs to be a better mechanism to determine where the faulty binding is declared. I'd like to see something like a stack trace for bindings..

I'm keeping the question open for a little while longer in case somebody knows of any other tools or methods of determining the place where a binding is declared in code or markup.

I've posted another [question regarding the style/binding being applied to the `MenuItems` here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526371/menuitem-added-programmatically-causes-binding-error).

Comment: Hrrm I recently wrote an answer about binding errors [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14482013/302677). The error is telling you it's trying to bind `<MenuItem HorizontalContentAlignment={ItemsControl.HorizontalContentAlignment}">`, but WPF is unable to find the `ItemsControl` (*"Cannot find source for binding"*). This is probably because [ContextMenus are not part of the same VisualTree as the rest of the application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5236744/302677), so you need to use the `PlacementTarget` in your binding to access the object the `ContextMenu` is attached to.

Comment: Did you try to trap the Exception when it happens?  From the Debug menu, select Exceptions... and drill down to the exception you're getting, and check the "Thrown" box.  Not sure if it will help, but it's one more thing to try.

Comment: But to answer the actual question you posted, I like to use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) for debugging WPF binding errors. It will let you navigate the VisualTree easily, and show you any binding problems

Comment: @Rachel - thanks for the info. I'll check out your post. I'll also give it a go with Snoop to see if I can shed some light on the matter that way. Otherwise, the problem is that I have no locations in code or XAML where a HorizontalContentAlignment would be bound.. Strange..

Comment: Any ideas how to use Snoop to determine where the BindingErrors may be happening? I tried the "Show only visuals with binding errors" and it found nothing..

Answer (score 108):

When debugging WPF binding errors, I find it easiest to break up the error by the semicolons, and start from the end

1. `System.Windows.Data Error: 4 :`
2. `Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment;`
3. `DataItem=null;`
4. `target element is 'MenuItem' (Name='');`
5. `target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')`

So starting from the end:

- #5 tells you what property contains the binding that is failing. In your case, it's `HorizontalContentAlignment`
- #4 is the element containing the failing property, which is a `MenuItem` without a `Name` property to identify it by

  So somewhere you have a `<MenuItem HorizontalContentAlignment="{Binding ...}" />` that is causing the binding error.
- #3 is the `DataItem`, or `DataContext`, that is behind the target element. It appears to be `null` for you, but that's not a problem since it looks like your binding isn't referencing the DataContext.

  But this does suggest that the `MenuItem` is not part of your regular `VisualTree`, since typically the `DataContext` is inherited from the parent object.
- #2 contains the actual binding error and information about the binding. It can actually be further broken up into multiple parts.

  - `Cannot find source for binding`
  - `with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''.`
  - `BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment;`

  "Cannot find source" means the binding can't find the source object to bind to, and in your case, that source object should be `{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}` (`FindAncestor` and `AncestorLevel=1` are defaults for a `RelativeSource`, so I'm ignoring those)

  And the last part of #2 shows the `Path` you are trying to bind to: `HorizontalContentAlignment`

So to put it all together, somewhere in your code there is a `<MenuItem>` which is trying to bind its `HorizontalContentAlignment` to an `ItemsControl.HorizontalContentAlignment`, but the binding can't find the `ItemsControl`.

You're using a `RelativeSource FindAncestor` binding to find the `ItemsControl`, which searches up the visual tree to find the closest `ItemsControl`, and it's not finding one so there must be no `ItemsControl` higher up in the VisualTree hierarchy from the `MenuItem`.

I often see this problem with `ContextMenus` because they are not part of the same `VisualTree` as the rest of your XAML code. (To reference the object in the main `VisualTree` that a `ContextMenu` is attached to, you can use the `PlacementTarget` property, like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5236744/302677).

Once you understand the binding error, its often easy to find the source of it in your XAML.

Depending on my application size, I usually do one of the following:

- Search the application for the "target element" from the binding error (in your case, `MenuItem`), and see if any of them are setting the "target property" (`HorizontalContentAlignment`) with a binding
- Search the application for the "target property" from the binding error (`HorizontalContentAlignment`) to find the binding causing this problem
- Search the application for something fairly unique from the binding text shown in the binding error. In your case, you could try searching on `{x:Type ItemsControl}` which would be part of your `RelativeSource` binding, and there shouldn't be too many search results for such a phrase.
- Use a 3rd party tool like [Snoop](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2013/01/21/snoop-firebug-for-wpf-applications/) or [WPF Inspector](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/) to track down the binding error at run time.

  I've only used Snoop before, but to use it you need to startup your application and run Snoop against it to inspect your application's VisualTree while it's running. You can then search the VisualTree by typing something like "MenuItem" in the search bar to filter the Visual Tree for all `MenuItems`, then look through their properties to find out which one has a binding error (the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property will be highlighted in red because of the binding error).

  It should be noted that if if your `MenuItem` is inside a `ContextMenu`, then you need to open that `ContextMenu` for the MenuItems to be drawn and show up in Snoop.

Comment: Rachel, thanks for taking the time to put this together. It might be useful for somebody else, so I'm going to up-vote for effort ;)  However, all of the things you said I knew and I've tried myself (with the exception of Snoop - which I did try and could not identify the problem). My question was more geared towards some mechanism to identify/locate the declaration that's causing the issue not unlike a stack trace. I was eventually able to find the problem but it was mostly dumb luck.. (I'll update the question).

Comment: The fact that this answer only had 4 (now 5) upvotes is a good example of how SO has changed over the years. It's been viewed over 1300 times! Why people so stingy? Mods be damned, delete this comment, don't delete it, whatevs.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could use this excellent application named [Snoop](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2013/01/21/snoop-firebug-for-wpf-applications/). It is for free in [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com). It helps me to find several Binding issues, and missin data contexts. It let explore the entire WPF Visual tree, and also give you the binding errors.

Hope Snoop could helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to WPF and I have exactly the same error. Although I have fixed it now, I really don't know how... below are steps I have tried:

First of all, I have:

1. a `<Menu>`
2. 2 `<ContextMenu>` defined in `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>`

I have tried to:

1. move one `<ContextMenu>` into `<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>`  -> error exists
2. Set and remove the style `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` for `<Menu>`, `<ContextMenu>`, `<MenuItem>`   ->error exists
3. Set the `Name` attribute for the `<MenuItem>` of the `<ContextMenu>` in `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>`    -> **no error!**
4. Remove the `Name` attribute    -> **still no error...**
5. Restart the VS  -> **the error seems gone forever...**

Eventually, I have

1. a `<Menu>`
2. a `<ContextMenu>` defined in `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>`
3. a `<ContextMenu>` defined in `<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>`

and NONE of them have set the style `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment`. And the error has gone...

Seems there is some refresh issue. So, for those who have the same problem, you could try to restart the VS or set the `Name` attribute for the `<MenuItem>`...

Answer (score 0):

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 - it isn't your problem, it's a WPF know problem. It's related comboboxes / menus whose items are changed dynamically. [See this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8028a46b-3080-40ad-aed2-e9417eb25381/binding-to-menuitem-result-in-binding-errors?forum=wpf). 
By the way you can ignore this errors, usually application works fine.