# Can't get selected item context menu

Tags: c#, wpf

here is my XAML and I am trying to get the value of the selected item in the Context Menu. I do not have the property of selected Item in my xaml. Is there another route i should go so that i am able to get the selected items from the context menu?

```
    <Style x:Key="ContextMenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SubItem}"/>
```

```
            <TextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Grid.RowSpan="2" x:Name="tbRadStudyType" Text="Click to set Care Plan Type" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="2" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviewMouseDownCommand}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding PlanMainList}" 
                                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContextMenuItemStyle}">

                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviewMouseDownCommand}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                        <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Term}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TextBox.ContextMenu>                     
            </TextBox>
```

Comment: ContextMenus are not part of the same VisualTree as the rest of your UI controls. If you want to use a binding to pull data into your ContextMenu, you need to use the `PlacementTarget` property to find the control the ContextMenu is attached to, and go from there. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5236744/302677) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then this is a common problem in WPF. It is caused because the `ContextMenu` having its own visual tree, quite separate from the main visual tree. The consequence of that is that it has no access to the `DataContext` from the main visual tree. The solution is to utilise a `Tag` property to pass the `DataContext`.

Rather than explaining the whole story once again, I'd rather suggest that you read my answers to the [Add context menu in datagrid, how to get the select Item value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610905/add-context-menu-in-datagrid-how-to-get-the-select-item-value) and [Bind Context Menu inside ItemsControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556561/bind-context-menu-inside-itemscontrol) questions here on Stack Overflow, which both explain the same thing in different situations.